# How do I show a graph on the Browser using VivaGraphJS on VUE 3?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vuejs3, vivagraphjs

I am trying to show a Graph on the browser using VUE 3 in the HOME view. To do that I installed VivaGraphJS with the command

```
npm i vivagraphjs
```

Then I took the minimal example from the website https://www.npmjs.com/package/vivagraphjs and tried several ways to include it on the template, but with with no success.

```
<template>
    <div id="graphDiv">{{graph()}}</div>
</template>


<script>
import * as Viva from '/node_modules/vivagraphjs/dist/vivagraph.js'

export default {
name: 'Home',
setup(){

const graph = () => {
       let graph = Viva.Graph.graph()
       graph.addLink(1, 2)

       let renderer = Viva.Graph.View.renderer(graph, {
       container: document.getElementById('graphDiv')
    })

    renderer.run()
}

return { graph }

}}

</script>
```

When I console.log() the renderer I can see the object in the console, so I know all the functions are working. But nothing is showed in the browser.

Thank you very much